# Can't screw PSU to computer case

Tags: power-supply, case, screws

As a software engineer willing to know more about hardware, I have started the dangerous quest of mounting my home computer myself.

The part I've been struggling the most so far is screwing things (like, literally), and after an hour working with the screws of death,  I believe I have found hell on earth:

[image: Power supply screws]

- My power supply is a Be Quiet! Power Zone (650W)
- I'm using a manual screwdriver (as I am not going to buy an electric one for mounting one single computer)
- The case is a Corsair 230T black (who'd have thought this was black?)
- The screws are the only available in the PSU box, which makes the choice rather easy
- I've tried with screws from the case package, and I *really* don't want to talk about this failure
- I thought if I manage to insert one properly, the other would be easy. Nope. Out of pure luck, I eventually managed to screw the top-left one properly and yet am still struggling with the others.
- It seems the screws need to be 100% precisely inserted, or they will no go further than 2 (what am I saying, it's even 1) turn with the screwdriver.
- I'm thinking the screws don't go further because they're not exactly centered (just a tiny bit to the left or to the right...)

Needless to say, the power supply is not moving in the case any more and I'm very tempted to leave it *as is* though that doesn't sound like a terribly good idea.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure the power supply is not in upside down?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are cross threading the screws. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncw0vIQF6cs

Comment: @ramhound - I'm not seeing any thumbscrews in that picture . . . Looks like standard 6-32 screws with a combo hex/Phillips head, and the issue appears to be the fact that there is lots of exposed thread, meaning the screws are nowhere close to being seated.  In addition to checking the PSU orientation, I'd check the seating . . . is it firmly seated and pushed in?

Comment: You can see a gap between the screw head and the back of the case. So they are not actually securing the PSU properly.

Comment: 1)don't ever use an electric screwdriver for installing computer hardware - it is too easy to strip screws or even break them. 2)There are different types of threading for different screws depending on where they go in a computer - are those definitely the screws that came with the PSU or case and not ones you had lying around from an HDD or another part?

Comment: I am fairly certain they were in the PSU box yes. I do believe the power supply is not upside down, though funnily there are holes that would make it possible in the other way around (I've tried it, it wasn't either).

Comment: it wasn't easier*

Comment: Sometimes it helps to spin the screw in reverse about 1/2 or 3/4 turn before spinning it the right way when you first start. If you try to put the screws in to the power supply separate of the case, do they go in fine then? If you can't even screw them in that way, then the screws may be damaged - inspect the threading and look for anything that is bent or worn.

Comment: There is also the possibility that the power supply just didn't get drilled properly. It isn't that uncommon. I ran into that quite frequently, even with higher grade equipment, when I was a telecom installer. I always carried a large selection of taps with me to fix holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

Take the PSU out again, so the case is not in the way. Try to get the screws into the holes in the PSU by hand, if they fit and the thread is ok, that should go smoothly. If the thread is badly made or slightly damaged by your workings, you might encounter a bit of resistance but not much at that diameter. Maybe overcome that with the **careful** help of a screwdriver, but make sure you are actually doing good (right alignment, right size). You would be basically "recutting" parts of the thread so they match up with the rest. If it doesn't feel right, cancel it. Dismiss the screws and see below.

If the screws really only go in a tiny bit like in your picture, you most likely have the wrong screws (too big or wrong threading) for some reason. If you can, try different ones, maybe your case came with a bag of spares (kinda likely).

Once you know you have the correct screws, use them to screw that PSU (into your case). ;-)

bonne chance, good luck

Comment: I have tried the screws before putting the power supply in the case. They seemed to fit but it was even *very* difficult to do so. I was even surprised when I managed to make one fit completely (and I'll admit I'm very relunctant to remove it now that it is my only success so far).

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: If it is seated properly and doesn't move, you can of course leave it like that. Just keep in mind that when you transport the machine by car for example, it might pull loose and damage things inside. For regular use you were not going for "earthquakeproof" to begin with, so you should be fine. :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I'll just tell myself that I will try to fix it properly when the time comes and die before actually doing it. ;-)